# FlatBuffers: how to generate name() method in Python

Tags: python, flatbuffers

in java, FlatBuffers will generate name() method for enums, which is very helpful.

```
  public static final String[] names = { "SUCCESS", "TIME_OUT", "UNKNOWN_ERROR", };

  public static String name(int e) { return names[e]; }
```

so does it in c++

```
inline const char **EnumNamesResultCode() {

  static const char *names[] = { "SUCCESS", "TIME_OUT", "UNKNOWN_ERROR", nullptr };

  return names;

}

inline const char *EnumNameResultCode(ResultCode e) { return EnumNamesResultCode()[static_cast<int>(e)]; }
```

but in python, there is no such method. it just generate a pure class with some constants.

```
class ResultCode(object):

    SUCCESS = 0

    TIME_OUT = 1

    UNKNOWN_ERROR = 2
```

how to generate name() method in python?

in other words, how can I get enum names in python?

Comment: I dont know much of Python and C++, can you tell what exactly you want in Python in English

Comment: @RahulAgarwal  I want flatbuffers to generate a method which can be used to get enum names.

Comment: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_python.html : Do check out this then

Comment: @RahulAgarwal yes but can't find anything helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If the class has a bunch of members, you can `dir()` the class and get the members.  You probably want to filter out things that start with `__`.  You can then create a mapping of the `class[member_name]` where `member_name` is what you want.